# ColdFusion 11 Update 19 - new SOLR collection "not found" issue

Tags: solr, coldfusion, jetty, coldfusion-11, cfindex

We are using a number of SOLR collections in CF 11. The collections that were created before we applied update 19 are being refreshed properly and work fine. However, the collections that were created after we installed update 19 do not function correctly. Here is what we see:

1. A new collection is being created the right way: a new directory (with the correct subdirectories) appears under /cfusion/collections. A new collection appears in CF Administrator under Data & services -->ColdFusion Collections.
   However, running this line:  throws  "org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException".
2. When we try to refresh that new collection by running "http://localhost:8987/solr/#collection#/dataimport?command=delta-import&commit=true" we get 404 Not Found error:
   [Error on a newly created collection refresh attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZC4c0.png)

Our older collections (created before we applied CF update 19) are being refreshed correctly using the same exact command.

What did we break/miss with update 19 that might cause this problem? Any thoughts or leads are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are the `#`-s actually present in your URL when you're making the request? They should not be there - they are html anchors and are never sent to the server. Instead you probably want just `/solr/collection/dataimport` or something similar.

Comment: I think he has a variable `collection` that is meant to output in the URL, but it's missing `<cfoutput>` tags.

Comment: Yes, #-s here are just the CF variables. The problem essentially is that: aaa is the collection created before we applied CF update 19 -  the following works perfectly http://localhost:8987/solr/aaa/dataimport?command=delta-import&commit=true              Now bbb is the collection created using the same exact code but after CF update 19 has been installed. The following throws "404 not found" http://localhost:8987/solr/bbb/dataimport?command=delta-import&commit=true        Any ideas?